# How to develop patience?

Tags: mind

We pray to god to end our sufferings. But many times, results don't come easily and quickly.
In that time how to develop patience and not fall into despair and depression.

Sometimes doubts gets created, if we are on the right path. Should we choose some other path.
Since we have not seen god, It is very easy for us to doubt if we are on the right path or not.

How to deal with it ?

Comment: I don't know about your path. But I remember a wise man once said - that siddhis (some special powers) do come to a person on a spiritual path. This is **must**. But it shouldn't be used for pleasure purposes. Second, any path where suffering lessons is always the right path.